# The fastest way to convert Surface to Bitmap/Image c#

Tags: c#, bitmap, surface

Is there any faster way to convert Surface to Bitmap? At this point I use this :

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(SlimDX.Direct3D9.Surface.ToStream(s, SlimDX.Direct3D9.ImageFileFormat.Bmp));
```

(s is Surface)

I need to capture screen as fast as it is possible, I used to use GDI, but it's too slow, then I read that using DirectX will be faster, but the time of capturing screen and converting surface to bitmap is approximately same.